# Comparing two variance matrices

Tags: multivariate-analysis, references, covariance-matrix

I am looking for bibliographical reference for comparing two variance matrices with he following criterion:

$\text{Var}[X] \geq \text{Var}[Y] \quad \text{if} \quad \text{Var}[X]-\text{Var}[Y] \succeq 0$

This means that $X$ has greater variance than $Y$ if the difference of their variance matrices is positive semi-definite.

Any references to books or articles with citations that explain why this is a valid and common criterion to compare variability of random vectors is appreciated. If that is not possible any help on how to search for it would be ok.

Comment: Where did you encounter such a criterion?

Comment: @kjetil, I first saw of it in Wikipedia when studing the Gauss Markov theorem which asses that least squares is BLUE. I have used on my thesis and nobody complained. It makes sense because for any fixed $\alpha$, Var[$\alpha^t X$]$\geq$Var[$\alpha^t Y$].

Comment: Curious if you found such citations?

Answer (score 2):

This order is the standard order on positive-definite matrices.  It is sometimes called the "Loewner order", or the cone ordering in the cone of positive-definite matrices.  Googling those terms will give many hits.  A book dedicated to inequalities and orders is [Marshall, Olkin, Arnold:  "Inequalities: Theory
of Majorization and Its Applications",  chapter 14 D (second edition)](https://www.bookdepository.com/Inequalities-Theory-Majorization-Its-Applications-Albert-W-Marshall/9781493938278?ref=grid-view&qid=1574735003270&sr=1-2).

Comment: Go to google scholar and search flor "mathematical statistics loewner order"